# How to make radio buttons in Django admin

Tags: django, django-admin

Does Django itself provide radio button models?
I was trying to find out how to make radio buttons in Django admin, but since there is nothing related to that, It seems like Django doesn't have radio buttons as default.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Django model with choices will make use of select by default. To use radio buttons, you will have to to use the RadioSelect widget. See [django docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/ref/forms/widgets/#widgets-inheriting-from-the-select-widget)

Answer (score 2):

This is too late but could be useful for other
you can define the radio button in your admin like this:

radio_fields = {'gender': admin.VERTICAL}

Comment: Please explain how and why you are using dict ? where should I add this code, models or forms?